# JS Puppeteer how to get 3 cell from all table rows

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I want to scrape a table with puppeteer. I only need an a tag in the third table cell of each row. How do I only select a specific cell from every row of a table??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `nth-child` selector to achieve it,

something like this should work:

```
await page.$$eval('table tbody tr td:nth-child(3) a', (rows) => {
  return Array.from(rows, (row) => {
    return {
      name: row.innerText,
      link: row.href,
    };
  });
});
```

The previous piece of code will select the 3rd cell for each rows and return an Array of objects with the link and inner text